# Why does Apache with mod_wsgi force a download of .py files instad of executing them?

Tags: apache-2.4, python, django, mod-wsgi

**Why does Apache with mod_wsgi force a download of .py files instead of executing them?**

I'm trying to run Django, but the first issue I have is .py files not executing.

I'm following the docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

- I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 installed and enabled
- `apachectl configtest` Syntax OK
- All files chowned to `www-data:www-data`
- .py files are `chmod +x`
- `/var/log/apache2/access.log` is empty

`/var/log/apache2/error.log` contains:

> Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1k mod_wsgi/4.6.8
> Python/3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations

The .htaccess file at root has

```
RewriteEngine on
ServerSignature Off
```

Directory of /var/www/html/example.com/public_html is this:

[image]

This is what I see; clicking on a .py file forces it to download.

[image]

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf:**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>


Alias /static /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/static
Alias /media /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/media

<Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /  /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/contact/wsgi.py

WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-home=/var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact

WSGIProcessGroup example.com

WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi

 <Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/contact>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all grantd
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html>
AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

   # Allow .htaccess files
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>


Alias /static /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/static
Alias /media /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/media

<Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /  /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/contact/wsgi.py

WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-home=/var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact

WSGIProcessGroup example.com

WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi

 <Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/contact/contact>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>


<Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html>
AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Do you have any entry with RemoveHandler?

Answer (score -1):

`WSGIScriptAlias` does not provide a way to click and view service for python, you should use your python-defined route (path) to access your application. Open links to `.py` files may go through the static file serving instead of WSGI.

cuz you mount your WSGI application at the root, **try open** `/` instead of `/contact` to see if it works.

Comment: I'm already using `WSGIScriptAlias /` instead of  `WSGIScriptAlias /contact`

Comment: @BlueDogRanch so please try open `/` in your browser instead of opening `/contact`